# AWS VPC can't access Internet despite configuring NAT, Internet Gateway according to rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, nat, aws-nat-gateway

I'm a bit lost on that one - I've followed AWS documentation and it seems that there is nothing more I can find. The situation summary is that I have an EC2 instance within a VPC and it can't reach the Internet despite following Amazon AWS instructions in setting up a NAT for the VPC. Details below:

1. I have a VPC with one subnet (CIDR 10.0.0.0/24) and one EC2 instance in (it has private IP address within VPC only, 10.0.0.168)
2. I have created an Internet Gateway and attached it to the said VPC.
3. I have created a Network ACL with All Traffic Allow for 0.0.0.0/0 for both Inbound and Outbound traffic and attached the ACL to the VPC's only subnet.
4. VPC subnet security group also allows all traffic in and out for 0.0.0.0/0
5. I have created a NAT Gateway which has a private IP address within the VPC (10.0.0.95) and a public Elastic IP address (let's say 18.154.34.97, but I assume this doesn't matter). This NAT Gateway is attached to the VPC's only subnet.
6. I have created routing table that is associated with VPC's subnet (10.0.0.0/24) and contains two entries:

```
    Destination     Target
    10.0.0.0/24     local
    0.0.0.0/0       nat-gateway-id
```

7. In order to access the VPC, I have created a Client VPN Endpoint with addresses range 10.1.0.0/22 and associated it with the proper VPN subnet.
8. I can connect to the Client VPN Endpoint using OpenVPN and ssh into the EC2 instance. However, from that instance I cannot access the Internet. Similarly, when connected to this Client VPN Endpoint my local machine also stops being able to access the Internet. I have tried pinging the NAT address within the VPC (10.0.0.95) and it's unreachable from either machine.
9. Everything is I've set up green, active etc. when using the Reachability Analyzer I get the following:

```
Route table rtb-(...) does not have an applicable route to igw-(...)
```

I route things to NAT, not to Internet Gateway, as I understood this is the correct way to go about this when I have private IP addresses only within the VPC.

```
Traffic cannot reach the internet through internet gateway igw-(...) because the source address is not paired with a public IP address. To add or edit an IPv4 public IP address to the source, you can use an Elastic IP address.
```

If I understand NAT correctly, it becomes the source address for the Internet Gateway after receiving data from one of the within-VPC instances. This NAT has a public Elastic IP address.

```
Internet gateway igw-(...) cannot accept traffic with spoofed addresses from the VPC.
```

It should not be getting any such traffic, as it should go through the NAT, right?

I'm at loss what I have I missed here...

Comment: If you only have one subnet, there is no need for a NAT Gateway. It will be a public subnet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have **two subnets**. One public and one private.

**Public subnet**

Public subnet can have **enable public IP** set. It should have **NAT gateway** and a route table:

```
 Destination     Target
    10.0.0.0/24     local
    0.0.0.0/0       internet-gateway
```

**private subnet**

Your private **instance** should in the private subnet. The subnet should have route table:

```
    Destination     Target
    10.0.0.0/24     local
    0.0.0.0/0       nat-gateway-id
```

**NACL**

Its better to leave the **default NACLs** as they are. Its very easy to mess them up. You should be able to control access to and from your instance using security groups only.

Answer (score 1):

The NAT gateway must be in a public subnet with a route table that routes internet traffic to an internet gateway.